# M-reducable set

Tags: logic, computability

I have found the following task:
Show that K (the halting set) is m-reducable to the zero functions $$ K \leq_M\{x | f_x = 0\}$$

We need to find a total-computable function h, such that:
$$ x \in K \iff h(x) \in \{x | f_x = 0\} $$
The i have found this solution:

h(x,y) = t (if f_x (x)↓}

h(x,y) = ↑ (else)

But shouldn't h be a **total**-computable function? And h is not-total ? And why does it have two arguments? Any tips? Am I understanding things wrong?

page 5:
[http://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/~gao-xf/computability/Document/10-Reducibility.pdf](http://www.cs.sjtu.edu.cn/%7Egao-xf/computability/Document/10-Reducibility.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct; the slides are somewhat confusingly written.

The function $f_{\bf 0}$ is **not** the desired $m$-reduction. Indeed it can't possibly be since the arity is wrong: an $m$-reduction is unary, but $f_{\bf 0}$ is binary. Instead, $f_{\bf 0}$ is an oddly-packaged description of the *outputs* of the intended $m$-reduction of $K$ to $\{x: \phi_x\simeq{\bf 0}\}$.

The point is that for each $x$, the function $$\eta_x: y\mapsto f_{\bf 0}(x,y)$$ is a partial computable function with the property that $\eta_x\simeq {\bf 0}$ iff $x\in K$. *(I'm writing "$\simeq$," rather than "$=$," for equality of possibly-partial functions.)*

The idea is then that our $h$ should be a function sending $x$ to **an index for** the partial computable function $\eta_x$. That is:

> Suppose we have a total computable function $h$ such that for each $x$ we have $$\phi_{h(x)}\simeq \eta_x.$$ Then $h$ is an $m$-reduction of $K$ to $\{x: \phi_x\simeq {\bf 0}\}$.

The existence of such an $h$ is then justified by the s-m-n theorem, applied to the partial computable *binary* function $f_{\bf 0}$. So when the author more-or-less says "$f_{\bf 0}(x,y)$ demonstrates $K\le_m\{x: \phi_x\simeq {\bf 0}\}$," what they mean is that we can extract an appropriate reduction from $f_{\bf 0}$, not that $f_{\bf 0}$ is itself such a reduction.

Comment: Is this a good solution : i is such that f_i = 0 and j is such that f_j != 0.
h(x) = i (if f_x (x)↓} and  h(x) = j (else)  ?